# Is there a way to repeat a structure in HTML and only having to change the content?

Tags: html, css

*I've been self-teaching myself web design.*

I have this section on a page that displays a person's searches (like any other search engine) and that section's structure repeats itself over and over again. I was wondering if there was a type of way that I could code only one section and just have the content change (like a loop in Java)? Could this be achieved with an 'id' attribute?

*(If I asked this question wrong or could word it better, please let me know)*

Comment: Hi @Paige please post here the code you tried. I think you're looking for a back end framework or JavaScript/front-end which will provide you data loops like Ajax.

Comment: It all depends on the code you are writing with, HTML does not have something that allows this, but using HTML along with say PHP, you can use functions to write logic that may create a navigation bar, passing in parameters for say the buttons. You keep those functions on a php page called say **includes.php**, then you can use a built in php function to include that file into your php pages, each one, only writing your main code for your navigation once, but including in all your pages.

Comment: @dalelandry thank you! I'll go read up about PHP and javascript

Comment: Here is good video showing exactly what I am talking about using php, happy coding ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMTvi3Rys-o

Comment: and this one...  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLswm39reho

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple method with pure HTML/CSS. Usually JavaScript is used to dynamically insert HTML elements based on a *template*. This means the elements will appear in the DOM, but not the HTML source code*. There are many template engines (often included in *frameworks*.)

Here is a live demo of how to use `each` blocks in a SvelteJS template: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/each-blocks

```
// index.svelte
<script>
    let cats = [
        { id: 'J---aiyznGQ', name: 'Keyboard Cat' },
        { id: 'z_AbfPXTKms', name: 'Maru' },
        { id: 'OUtn3pvWmpg', name: 'Henri The Existential Cat' }
    ];
</script>

<h1>The Famous Cats of YouTube</h1>

<ul>
    {#each cats as { id, name }, i}
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={id}">
            {i + 1}: {name}
        </a></li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

In the code above, Svelte takes the index.svelte file and transforms it into HTML (with JS to generate the elements in the each loop).

*It is also possible to use a server-side templating engine. Then the elements will appear in the HTML source code.

---

There is another concept called *web components*: HTML/CSS/JS like above is packaged together into a re-usable *component*. This is probably the closest to using pure HTML/CSS: if the component is already written, components can usually be used just like custom HTML tags. Data is passed to components via child elements and/or tag attributes. Simple example of a SvelteJS component: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/nested-components

---

**Popular [Web Template Engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system)**

- [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/)
- [Pug](https://pugjs.org/)

**Popular [Web Frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework)** (that support templates)

- [SvelteJS](https://svelte.dev/)
- [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/)
- [AngularJS](https://angular.io)